# How to exclude a specific string constant?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Can regular expression be utilized to match any string except a specific string constant (i.e. `"ABC"`)?

Is it possible to exclude just one specific string constant?

Comment: Which tool are you using? Depending upon the tool, there might be a way to specify this external to your regex.  grep supports a -v option to invert the sense of the match, for example.

Comment: So are you looking to match every character of a given string, except the ABC part of it?  In other words, "A string with ABC" would match "A string with ".

Answer (score 205):

You have to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
(?!^ABC$)
```

You could for example use the following.

```
(?!^ABC$)(^.*$)
```

If this does not work in your editor, try this. It is tested to work in ruby and javascript:

```
^((?!ABC).)*$
```

Comment: This will work if you're looking for a string that does not include ABC.  But is that the goal?  Or is the goal to match every character except ABC?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, you are right - my suggestion only avoids strings starting with ABC - I forgot to anchor the assertion. Going to correct that.

Comment: That's still different than what I was thinking.  Perhaps the questioner will clarify what they're looking for.

Comment: I find it quite clear - "any string except a specific string [constant]" hence any string (including strings containing ABC) except ABC itself.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right.  If so then you're answer is perfect.  You can see my answer to see how I interpreted it.

Comment: not working in Javascript. text = 'hi ABC wow';
regex = /(?!^ABC$)/
console.log(text.match(regex));

Comment: You only used the assertion but forgot the matching expression - use (?!^ABC$)(^.*$) and it works.

Comment: I was helping a friend recently to do something very similar.  However, he didn't want to match the string if it contained a string anywhere inside of it.  So I wrote a slightly modified version of your expression *(?!.*ABC)^.*$* and this works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

In .NET you can use grouping to your advantage like this:

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=65b32601-2326-4ece-912b-6dcefd883f31

You'll notice that:

```
(ABC)|(.)
```

Will grab everything except ABC in the 2nd group.  Parenthesis surround each group.  So (ABC) is group 1 and (.) is group 2.

So you just grab the 2nd group like this in a replace:

```
$2
```

Or in .NET look at the Groups collection inside the Regex class for a little more control.

You should be able to do something similar in most other regex implementations as well.

UPDATE: I found a much faster way to do this here:
http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=997ce4a2-878c-41f2-9d28-34e0c5080e03

It still uses grouping (I can't find a way that doesn't use grouping).  But this method is over 10X faster than the first.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't easy, unless your regexp engine has special support for it. The easiest way would be to use a negative-match option, for example:

```
$var !~ /^foo$/
    or die "too much foo";
```

If not, you have to do something evil:

```
$var =~ /^(($)|([^f].*)|(f[^o].*)|(fo[^o].*)|(foo.+))$/
    or die "too much foo";
```

That one basically says "if it starts with non-`f`, the rest can be anything; if it starts with `f`, non-`o`, the rest can be anything; otherwise, if it starts `fo`, the next character had better not be another `o`".

Comment: That won’t allow the empty string, `f`, `fo` and `foo`.

Comment: @Gumbo: It allows the empty string just fine; notice that ($) is the first alternative, so ^$ (empty string) is accepted. I tested it, and at least in perl 5.0.10 the empty string is accepted.

Comment: ... sorry, perl 5.10.0, of course!

Answer (score 7):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(.{0,2}|([^A]..|A[^B].|AB[^C])|.{4,})$
```

It describes three cases:

1. less than three arbitrary character
2. exactly three characters, while either

   - the first is not `A`, or
   - the first is `A` but the second is not `B`, or
   - the first is `A`, the second `B` but the third is not `C`
3. more than three arbitrary characters

Answer (score 6):

You could use negative lookahead, or something like this:

```
^([^A]|A([^B]|B([^C]|$)|$)|$).*$
```

Maybe it could be simplified a bit.