# Excluding strings from one string using Regex in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring

I want to do pretty much the same as in [Excluding strings using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792367/excluding-strings-using-regex) but I want to do it iOS using Regex. So I basically I want to find matches in a string and then remove them from the string so if I have a string like this, `Hello #world @something` I want to find `#world` & `@something` and then remove them from the string so it just becomes `Hello`. I already have this expression that removes `#world` and `something` but not the `@`, `#[\\p{Letter}]+|[^@]+$` I solved the `@` problem by doing this

```
NSString *stringWithoutAt = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",atString] withString:@""];
NSString *stringWithoutTag = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:tagString withString:@""];
```

So for the first one I end up with `Hello #world` and the second one `Hello @something`. But is there a way of using Regex or something else to remove both the `#world` and the `@something` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex in iPhone in two ways:-

1>Using RegExKitLIte as framework [see the tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-regular-expression-tutorial-regexkitlite-framework/)

2>Using NSRegularExpression & NSTextCheckingResult

```
NSStirng *string=@"Your String";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@[a-z]*#[a-z]*" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{
    // your statement if it matches
}];
```

Here any expression after@ and expression after # is being concatenated

and in the statement you can replace it by space to get your expression

if u simply want modified string do this :-

```
 NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0
range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"$2$1"];
```

Comment: Sorry but can you explain exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Is there any way apart from using Regex to do this?

Comment: I have written a regex expression that matches an expression @[letters]#[letters]and then you can replace it with @" ".in the block i provided.

Comment: There are other ways such as find the @ sign in your string and taking it's position remove every character after it using substring method.

Comment: I found out a simpler solution, `NSString *stringWithoutAnything = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @%@",tagString,atString] withString:@""];`