# Get URLs and ignore others

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get all href urls except those that contain "get/index.php" and "PICSNUM"

```
<a href="/video5505298733/travel_and_tourism_recovery_coronavirus." title="The places and companies missing tourist dollars most.">The places and companies missing tourist dollars most.</a></p><p class="info"><span class="bg"><span class="duration">10 min</span><a href="/get/index.php?id=qafMsaaScGLPuKqGuanBpZjHtGHKppeHpJu5r6G9raaHoqa3tJS-ope5tJK6s5TLqp8"><span class="name">CORONAVIRUS</span></a><span><span class="bolder"> - </span> 1.7k <span class="bolder">Views</span></span><span class="text-disabled"><span class="bolder"> - </span> 2 days ago</span><span class="bolder"> - </span></span></p></div></div>               <div class="thumb-lock "><div class="thumb-big"><div class="thumb"><a href="/midia54891337/PICSNUM/russia_fire_coronavirus_patients_intl"><img src="lightbox.gif" data-src="https://cdn-pic.cnews-cdn.com/videos/thumbs169/22/d3/a2/22d3a23423dfda7f5/22d3a2dfbb9fdfgd43f5.PICNUM.jpg"  /></a>
```

I looked at this topic and how negative lookahead works but I don't think I understand how it works
[Regex to include one thing but exclude another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486738/regex-to-include-one-thing-but-exclude-another)

I tried this but it didn't work

```
(?<=href=")^(?!\/(get|PICSNUM))[a-z0-9-_\/.]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/bG8Rq4/2

I changed for that the result was better but still a part of the urls containing PICSNUM is still returning

```
(?<=href=")(?!\/(get|PICSNUM))[a-z0-9-_\/.]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/12HHHt/1

```
/video5505298733/travel_and_tourism_recovery_coronavirus.
/midia54891337/
```

Where am I going wrong?
Regex is a little confusing to me

Comment: Did u tried to add a closure tag for the HREF? I mean, u are telling it that i must began with 'href="' and then something, but never what can be found at the end. I tried with: (?<=href=")(?!\/(get|PICSNUM))[a-z0-9-_\/.]+(?="), and now it seem to pick only the url that ends without encounter get or PICSNUM. Let me know if u have still some problem with it.

Comment: You should use DOM parsing methods, it will be much easier then, since after you get plain text from all hrefs you will be able to use simpler string check approaches. With regex, you probably want `href="\K(?![^"]*\/(?:get\/index\.php|PICSNUM))[^"]+`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/12HHHt/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dom parser to get the value of the href. If you have found the values, you could use a negative lookahead to assert the string does not start with either `/get` or contains `/PICSNUM`

The reason the pattern does not work yet is because `/PICSNUM` does not directly follow after the first lookbehind.

```
^(?!(?:/get|\S*/PICSNUM))\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Txhg4p/1) | [Php demo wit DOMDocument](https://3v4l.org/tLrtW)

You could use the alternation in the existing pattern, but that would not be very efficient.

Instead you could use a capturing group:

```
href="(?!(?:/get/index\.php|\S*/PICSNUM/))([a-z0-9-_/.]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6TuQk/1)