# Is there anyway i can disable user to input a custom word or two in jquery validate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate plugin to validate my php form, now i'm stuck with validating for a custom word, what i want to do is, disable user to input two words, for example:

word1, word2.

Is there any simple way to do it, i tried with some custom methods, but i have no idea what am i doing. Is there anyone able to provide me one?

```
custom: {
required: true,
words: "word1,word2",
},
```

And in my controller

```
custom: function( value, element ) {
return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\word1,word2\)?$/.test(value);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a method for words (same as 'words:') to declare a custom function which jqvalidate will use. This should be added before you call jQuery.validate();

```
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("words", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^/(?!Hello)(?!World)$/.test(value);
    }, "Only Hello and World are allowed");
```

See [validator AddMethod](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) for reference. No controller code is required.

Try to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string) for answers within stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't need what you made mate, i need to disallow words such as Hello, Word, not only allow them, so i basically need opposite of what you made.

Comment: Try adding a not in  the regex. it will do the opposite.

Comment: Do you mind writing it in the regex, i'm feeling dumb on this one. Thanks. I understand the addmethod method tho.