# What is a regular expression pattern for rule 'doesn't contain a word W'?

Tags: regex, robotframework

I want to test the web-element style: it shouldn't contain words "disabled" or "inactive".

Comment: possible duplicate of [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need a "negative" regex? Why not create a regex that tests that it contains "disabled" or "inactive", and test for it to be false?

`'status: inactive' !~ /(disabled|inactive)/`

Comment: "Should Not Match Regexp" -- I've overlooked this keyword in the robotframework

Answer (score 2):

Using negative lookahead:

```
>> 'status: inactive ' =~ /(?!.*(disabled|inactive))^/
=> nil
>> 'status: disabled' =~ /(?!.*(disabled|inactive))^/
=> nil
>> 'status: enabled' =~ /(?!.*(disabled|inactive))^/
=> 0
```