# Route regex requirements : exclude specific words

Tags: regex, symfony, routes

I'm creating an application with Symfony 2.3.5 to manage my music.
I have some problems to configure my routes.

I want to create 3 routes :

- Show Artist : `/music/mickael_jackson`
- Edit Artist : `/music/mickael_jackson/edit`
- Show Album : `/music/mickael_jackson/thriller`

As you can show, there will be a conflict between routes for 'Edit Artist' and for 'Show album' : 'Edit Artist' is catched as the 'Show album route' and give me a 404 not found.

I'm trying to use regular expressions to exclude keywords `edit` and `delete` from route 'Show album'.

I have found one here : [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string) (Accepted answer with a little change), but it doesn't work, I have an error because my route 'Show album' did not match regex.

Exception :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "nameCanonical" for route "corum_music_album_show" must match "/(?!edit|delete)" ("beneath_the_encasing_of_ashes" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in CorumMusicBundle:Artist:show.html.twig at line 36.
```

My route :

```
* @Route(
*         "{artistNameCanonical}/{nameCanonical}",
*         name = "corum_music_album_show",
*         requirements={"nameCanonical" = "^/(?!edit|delete)$"},
*         options = {"expose"=true}
* )
```

I can't find what's wrong in the configuration.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this pattern `^(?!.*(edit|delete)$).*`
I don't know Symfony either

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forward slash,

```
*         requirements={"nameCanonical" = "^(?!edit|delete)$"},
```

since it's already included in your total path.

Otherwise, the regex looks okay to me; nice work, finding the answer on your own. Most people new to regular expressions have trouble with applying lookaround assertions.

Comment: Thank's for help but I still have the same exception. Regular expressions are the most complicated things I learn and it is still a mystery to me...

Comment: Hm, Sorry, I don't know enough about Symfony to help you, then. I've upvoted your question though; hopefully someone else can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your "Edit artist" route before "Show Album" route.
Of course, you won't be able to use "edit" as a name of an album, but I suppose you can live with that.