# Trying to do multiline perl regular expression with grep excluding a phrase

Tags: regex, grep

So I'm trying to find functions that follow a pattern that exclude certain text. I know that if I'm looking for the following function

```
void myfunction(unsigned int a)
{
  //Something something here 
}
```

I can find this using the following

```
grep -IPzor 'void.*myfunction(\n|.)*\{(\n|.)*\}' ./*
```

and this seems to work properly. There are two things that I can't figure out how to do.

**1) What if I wanted to ignore functions that have the phrase 'something' in it?**

Let's say  I now have the following functions:

```
void myfunction1(unsigned int a)
{
  //Something something here 
}

void myfunction2(unsigned int a)
{
  //Other stuff here
}
```

and I only want to find things like function2. I tried to do:

```
grep -IPzor 'void.*myfunction(\n|.)*\{(\n|.)*(?!Something|something)(\n|.)*\}' ./*
```

And different variations of this don't work as I'd expect. It just finds nothing, and changing the phrase from 'something' to 'nothing' doesn't help.

**2) What if I want to find results where only an equal number of '{' and '}' are found?**

For this I don't know where to start. The results sometimes end up with extra text that follows the function...

**Here are some of the links I've read:**

[Regex (grep) for multi-line search needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines

[A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Comment: #1 your negative lookahead should have some flexibility in it: `(?!(?i).*something)`. #2 you cannot do with regular expressions

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks I've tried `grep -IPzor 'void.*myfunction(\n|.)*\{(\n|.)*(?!(?i).*Something|something)(\n|.)*\}' ./*` but it didn't seem to work. I suppose I don't know what `?i` does?

Comment: `perldoc perlre` -- it is a case insensitivity flag within a RE