# Regular expression to match text that "doesn't" contain a word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to exclude certain words using a regular expression.

Input Text:

```
aaa1234 cc bbb1234 c1234 cc dd aacc cccc ccadf cc
```

Output Text:

```
aaa1234 bbb1234 c1234 dd aacc cccc ccadf
```

exclude word: `cc`

I used `(^|\s)[^(cc)]+(\s|$)`

How to make the regular expression work?

Comment: Using [^(cc)] is same as [^c)(] I have changed the position to make it clear

Comment: A possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string

Comment: It's easier to just match what you want to exclude and replace it with the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\s+\bcc\b|\bcc\b\s+
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/25

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this **`(^|\s+)cc(\s+|$)`** to filter word **`cc`**, then replace it by empty string

```js
var word='aaa1234 cc bbb1234 c1234 cc dd aacc cccc ccadf cc';

console.log(word.replace(/(^|\s+)cc(\s+|$)/g,' ').trim());
```

Comment: Hmm ok, I see that now. It doesn't give the required output `aaa1234 bbb1234 c1234 dd aacc cccc ccadf` though but gives `aaa1234bbb1234 c1234dd aacc cccc ccadf`

Comment: The first leaves double spaces, the second leaves a trailing space (at the end).