# Regular Expression Exclude Word

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to replace all of the event handling functions whose name is either "eventHandler" or ends with "...EventHandler" to be encapsulated in a common event-handling function which does additional tasks before actually calling a event handler.

In short, I'm trying to do this (in sublime text editor) using the regular expression in find & replace:

*loginEventHandler*(args, callback) => **processEventHandler**(*loginEventHandler*, args, callback)

**[ Find ]**

(eventHandler|(?!processEventHandler)\w+EventHandler)((.*))

**[ Replace ]**

processEventHandler($1, $2)

This isn't working as expected. The find is also matching **rocessEventHandler** . How do I ignore matching the function if the function name is "processEventHandler"?

I tried solutions mentioned in the following questions, but didn't help.

[Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

[A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Here is the test result:

[image: Regular Expression Test Result]

Comment: You are using a regex tester that does not support Boost regex syntax. Use regex101 with PCRE as regex falvor. Also, please post the sample text in the question itself.

Comment: Here is the sample text:

loginEventHandler(err, result)


processEventHandler(loginEventHandler, err, result)


eventHandler(err, result)


appInitEventHandler(err, result)


initProcessEventHandler(err, result)


initprocessEventHandler(err, result)


generic(e, r)

Comment: Try [`(?i)(\b(?!process)\w*EventHandler)\(([^)]*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/dD9wI1/1)

Comment: How about this : https://regex101.com/r/dP7zD8/1 ?

Comment: @AnkitMishra Can not use ^ as the function will not be at the beginning of the string. For example: return someEventHandler(e, r);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your regex matches a part of the string with `process` is because the regex is not anchored at the start. If you need to match the strings at the start of a string, use `^`. If you plan to just match them inside a larger text, use `\b` (word boundary).

You can use a regex with a negative lookahead anchored at the leading word boundary:

```
(?i)(\b(?!process)\w*EventHandler)\(([^)]*)\)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD9wI1/1)

The regex (case-insensitive because of `(?i)` inline modifier) matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!process)` - a negative lookahead that fails a match if the following character sequence is found: `\w*` - zero or more alphanumeric symbols + `EventHandler`
- `\(` - opening parenthesis
- `([^)]*)` - zero or more characters other than `)`
- `\)` - closing parenthesis

Comment: The only thing I changed in your regular expression is, I used (.*) instead of ([^)]*) to match functions calls like the following one.


`return loginEventHandler(new Error('Invalid credentials'), result);`

Comment: If these strings are always on one line, this is OK. If this is not the case, use `(?si)(\b(?!process)\w*EventHandler)\((.*?)\);` or even `(?si)(\b(?!process)\w*EventHandler)\((.*?)\);(?=\h*(?:$|\R))`

Answer (score 0):

If the original EventHandler only has 2 arguments, this could work

**[ Find ]**

`(eventHandler|\w+EventHandler)\((.*?),(.*)\)`

**[ Replace ]**

`processEventHandler($1, $2, $3)`