# string matching using regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to match phone numbers like this,

It should have **3 digits** except `000,666` and any numbers between `900-999` followed by "-", then **2 digits** followed by "-", then **4 digits**.

For example:

```
123-75-3456  is a match
000- 23-3452 is not a match (no 000)
915-23-4534 is not a match (greater than 900)
```

This is where I currently stand:

```
[0-9&&^[000,666,[900-999]]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: Did you try to do anything ?

Comment: www.regex101.com

Comment: added what i tried.

Comment: Just a sec i am currently writing some code. You will then tell me if it is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one should do the trick:

```
^(?!000|666|9\d{2})\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

Edit: I find the negative look-ahead syntax in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string).

Edit 2: Here is a little code snippet for those who want to test it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!000|666|9\\d{2})\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Next number :");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sc.nextLine());
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Matches");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Doesn't match");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this please? what does \ do?

Comment: \ escapes another character. Here, d is escaped and means the same thing that [0-9] : any number between 0 and 9.

Comment: it works, understood the meaning too from this https://regex101.com/r/YVAXSQ/3 thanks