# Java regular expression for excluding certain numbers

Tags: java, regex, syntax

I am trying to do the following and I tried to find examples of how to do a proper exclusion but I couldn't quite get the hang of it.

[image: question]

I am supposed to exclude the numbers 000, 666, and all numbers between 900-999.

This was my attempt at the question but it doesn't include the exclusion:

```
String p = "(^[0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4}$)";
```

Which resulted in unnecessary matches:
[image: wrong answer]

This is my attempt at trying the exclusion but I'm unsure how:

```
String p = "(^[^666000]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4}$)";
```

Which resulted in some matches:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ``[0-900,^000,^666,^900-999]`` is not how character classes work... I suggest you read a tutorial.

Comment: Seems familiar.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135983/string-matching-using-regular-expressions-in-java

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match anything but `000`, `666` and `900-999`:

```
[1-578]\d\d|(?:0\d[1-9]|0[1-9]\d)|(?:6\d[0-57-9]|6[0-57-9]\d)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/arz5WC/1/)

**How this works**:

- `[1-578]\d\d` first alternative matches **all numbers starting with anything but `0`, `6` and `9`** i.e `1xx`, `2xx`, `7xx` etc. as represented here `[1-578]` which essentially means `1-5` or `7` or `8`.
- `(?:0\d[1-9]|0[1-9]\d)` matches **all numbers starting with `0`** and ensures that the number *shouldn't have* all three zeroes
- `(?:6\d[0-57-9]|6[0-57-9]\d)` matches **all numbers starting with `6`** and snsures that the number *shouldn't have* all three sixes

**Testing:**

Quick Test to validate if all are matched except `000`, `666` and `900-999`: [Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ttGAEd)

```
// Output for non-matching characters:
000, 666, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, ... and so on
```