# How to find non localised strings in a swift project

Tags: regex, swift, xcode, localization, xliff

How can I find all strings a project that are not being localised?

My goal is to add support for localisation by generating the XLIFF file, via Editor->Export For Localisation. In order to do that, I first added comment for Localiser where needed in the Storyboard.

Next, I need to find in the code all Strings that do not use NSLocalizedString("...", comment:"...").
Is there a way to find all these strings?

I didn't succeed writing a regex to find them, due to my lack of competence in regex.

My goal is to have a regex like this:
[withIdentifier: |NSLocalizedString(]".*"

in order to *find all strings surrounded by quotes, and that are not precedeed by some keywords*.

I tried with no success using negative look ahead with
[A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

It's not meant for automated replacement, but just to have a quick view if I haven't forgotten some strings.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think there is any such option :(

Answer (score 6):

**OBJC**

There is a possible way that you can find **ALL The Strings** which are not  used by `NSLocalizedString`

[image]

Goto **Product -> Analyze**

From Left Panel you can see

[image]

Where you can find each and every string which are not Localized

On tap on that

XCode will tell you issue

[image]

**SWIFT3**

**I am not Sure about solution NOT TESTED**

https://medium.com/@pinmadhon/finding-non-nslocalized-strings-in-xcode-8-in-swift-3-or-objc-589ee279a166

Comment: I couldn't see any Issue when running Analyze, Tried removing NSLocalizedString from one place and checked with complete Non Localized project as well. Do we need to enable it some way?

Comment: Thank you Mike! In an Objective-C project, I managed to get it working after adding another language in the project. However, in a Swift project, this system does not seem to work. I'm going to search more this way, because it is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @darksider Thanks, I tested it on swift and above wrote comment