# Need help in Regex (in Google Analytics)

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking

Setting up a goal in GA for my eCommerce store.

My products are all direct from the main URL without the **/products/** segment so I cant id them on GA. (e.g. they all look like this www.abc.com/baby-food)

Product pages: www.abc.com/word-word-.. and may include special characters.
Examples:

```
/captain-america-novelty-case
/mathematics-psle-revision-guide-3rd-edition
/pregnancy-day-by-day-3rd-edition#cxrecs_s
```

How do I use a single expression to id product page from the rest?

Examples of other pages from my site:

```
/shop/study/2018-study-necessities/prepare-for-school/general-materials
/shop/read/books/parenting
/Class/SearchResults/0/ALL 
/articles
/shop
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples you gave, what I see is that product pages all have several words in the 1st path level (before second `/`), so I would try something like this:

`^/[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+`

This will match urls which start with `/word1-word2` and can be followed by any substring.

In addition to setting up a goal, you might want to use content groups too:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167

To exclude certain words, you can try this:
[A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Not sure if GA supports this syntax, you have to test

Comment: Hello. I realised there are also specific /word1-word2 URLs I need to exclude. Do you think there is any expression that can exclude these few unique scenarios..? Thanks a lot.