# How to exclude a specific literal in Pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I have a `<input type="email"/>` and want it to
a) be a valid email address and
b) be something other than a given email address - let's say "root@localhost".

I had a look into the [Pattern for HTML input elements](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) and now I try to write a pattern **excludes** a specific value.

I stumbled across this Post: [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string) and looked into [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which was quite promising. Except for one thing:
If I use *negative lookahead*, it will also match anything that *starts with* the given exlusion, not only those that exactly match it!

My Code:

```
<input type="email" name="email" pattern="^(?!root@localhost).+$" required>
```

This will result in a validation error for

- empty text (correct)
- non-email-texts (correct)
- an email-address of "root@localhost" (correct)
- any email addresss starting with "root@localhost" (**wrong**)

Can you please help me on how to write a pattern that excludes exactly one email address from the validation?

Is using a pattern the right way here?

Thanks,
Alexander

Comment: Use `pattern="^(?!root@localhost$).*$"` or just `pattern="(?!root@localhost$).*"` since it is anchored by default.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew looks like you're right. `pattern="(?!root@localhost$).*` seems to work.  Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern="(?!root@localhost$).*"
```

Since the HTML5 patterns are anchored at both ends automatically you don't have to enclose the pattern with `^` and `$`.

The overall regex after HTML5 engine processes the  attribute value will look like `/^(?:(?!root@localhost$).*)$/` (in FF and Chrome, it will be compiled with `u` flag) and will match any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, from the start till the end of a string, that is not equal to `root@localhost` string.

Comment: How would I exclude multiple different values? For example I'd like to exclude `root@localhost` *and* `root@gmail`.

Comment: @DominikKrzywiecki  `pattern="(?!root@(?:localhost|gmail)$).*"`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript validation

```
function validate(form) {
    if (form.email === "root@localhost") {
        return false;
    }

    return /.+\@.+\..+/.test(form.email);
}
```

Comment: there are reasons for that. Pattern is an elegant way to perform a validation on any input field where no piece of Javascript needs to be written.