# Regular expression - How to exclude certain string from the results set?

Tags: regex

I am pretty new in Regular Expression.

**Input**

```
/shop/earrings
/shop/yellow-gold-earrings
/shop/white-gold-earrings
/shop/rose-gold-earrings

/shop/necklaces
/shop/yellow-gold-necklaces
/shop/white-gold-necklaces
/shop/rose-gold-necklaces

/shop/best-buy-earrings
```

**Regular Expression I used**

```
\/shop\/[a-z-]*-?earrings
```

**Desired Result**

```
/shop/earrings
/shop/yellow-gold-earrings
/shop/white-gold-earrings
/shop/rose-gold-earrings
```

**Actual Result**

```
/shop/earrings
/shop/yellow-gold-earrings
/shop/white-gold-earrings
/shop/rose-gold-earrings
/shop/best-buy-earrings
```

I do not want /shop/best-buy-earrings to be in the result. Please help me to fix the Regular Expression. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Comment: `\/shop\/(?!best-buy)[a-z-]*-?earrings`

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: What about `/shop/yellow-gold-best-buy-earrings` and `/shop/best-buy-gold-earrings`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `gold` to the regex before the `-` and surround with parenthesis:

```
\/shop\/([a-z-]*gold-)?earrings
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PCRE flavour, you can use:

```
\/shop\/(?!best-buy)(?:\w+-)*earrings
```

Or, if you can use other delimiter than slash:

```
/shop/(?!best-buy)(?:\w+-)*earrings
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/scxYPO/1)