# Exclude full word from regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text 'I'm Cristian'.

I'm using a regex to wrap every character in a different span element.
I want to exclude the word Cristian from the operation I tried with Negative lookahead but i can't put it to work .

the basic regex is this

```
/([^\x00-\x40]|\w|\S)/g
```

i tried with

```
/(?!Cristian)([^\x00-\x40]|\w|\S)/g
```

but it doesn't work
thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Comment: @AlbertoCasas I saw that, but unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```js
const string = `I'm Cristian`
console.log(string.replace(/\bCristian\b|([^\x00-\x40]|\w|\S)/g, 
     (match, group) => group == undefined ? match : `<span>${match}</span>`))
```

1. Add the `\bCristian\b` pattern to the expression before a pipe
2. Find out if your previous  captured pattern was found
3. If the previous is true, wrap the match with span, else, return the found text.

Comment: Thank youuuu. That worked. If you have time could you please explain why "?!" didn't work but "\b" did?? thanks. Really appreciated

Comment: @cri_pava `([^\x00-\x40]|\w|\S)` matches single character, and `(?!Cristian)` in front of that pattern cancels a match of that single character, but not a whole word like `Cristian`.

Comment: alright . i see now . Thanks , If you have time I have another question; if i have a span element inside an h1 element and i want to exclude the span element from the selection with a regex , there is a way to do so ?

Comment: @cri_pava That does not sound like a good idea, but `/(?<=<h1>(?:(?!<\/?h1>).)*?)<span>[^<]*<\/span>|\bCristian\b|([^\x00-\x40]|\w|\S)/gs` might work.

Comment: thanks . I see that is not a really good practice , but if i don't find a better solution i will need to use this . Thanks for all the help . appreciated