# regex to exclude string and delete line

Tags: regex, xml, sed

I have the following lines in an XML file

```
<User id="10338" directoryId="1" sometext txt text test/>
<User id="10359" directoryId="100" some more text text text/>
<User id="103599" directoryId="100" some more text text text/>
<User id="10438" directoryId="1" sometext txt text test/>
```

I am trying to remove any lines that start with User id=" but I want to keep the ones that have directoryId="1"

my current sed command is

```
sed -i '' '/<User id="/d' file.xml
```

I have looked at [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string) and a few other stack overflow posts but not able to get this to work. Please can someone help me write the regex. I essentially need to delete any lines that start with <User id= but excluding the ones where directoryId="1"

Comment: Try `sed -i '' -e '/directoryId="1"/b' -e '/<User id="/d' file.xml`

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i '' -e '/directoryId="1"/b' -e '/<User id="/d' file.xml
```

With this sed command,

- `/directoryId="1"/b` skips the lines containing `directoryId="1"` and
- `/<User id="/d` deletes the other lines that contain `<User id="`.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/cGvs4e).