# How to use two patterns in input?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a input like:

```html
<input type="text"
    name="firstname"
    id="firstname"
    placeholder="Name"
    maxlength="15"
    pattern="^[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŹŻŚ]+$"
    autofocus
    required >
```

Now I need to add another 'validation' what detect if in this input appear one of the following words:
['dog', 'cat']

So I would like to add patern or something else what check if input pass pattern="^[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŹŻŚ]+$" and do not let any word from this array ['dog', 'cat'] pass

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Answer (score 1):

maybe using lookahead, try replacing your pattern for:

```
(?=^[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŹŻŚ]+$)(?=^(?!.*cat|.*dog).*$)
```