# Negative look-ahead to exclude specific set of strings and allow all others

Tags: regex

I am searching a large number of text log files that contain various negative error codes, mostly 4-digits preceded with a minus sign, eg `-3304`, `-3315`, etc. I would like to exclude a small set of these error codes while allowing all others to match.

I have tried to use an adaptation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078953/645128):

```
 "^/(?!-3301|-3304|-3306|-3308|-3309)(-[0-9]{4})"
```

To exclude `-3301, -3304, -3306, -3308, -3309` but match all other 4-digit negative strings.
I know there are matches, such as `-3220` in the set of files, but they are not matching.

What have I missed in this attempt at a negative look ahead?

Comment: Probably, you want `-(?!330[14689])\d{4}(?!\d)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That just opened it up.  If you are interested, please place in an answer?  BTW, is `\d` equivalent to `[0-9]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some a `/` char before the number matching pattern that is not supposed to be part of a negative number. Besides, you are only matching at the start of string with `^`.

Note that you match more than 4-digit numbers with that pattern, you need a digit boundary on the right.

You can use

```
-(?!330[14689])\d{4}(?!\d)
```

*Details*:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?!330[14689])` - on the right, there should be no `330` and then a digit from `14689` set
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately on the right.