# str_detect exclusion of word combinations

Tags: r, string

I am doing a content analysis of french politician's twitter posts dealing with immigration.
As I only recently  started working with strings, I am currently facing some problems regarding the exclusion of word combinations.
Notably, I defined the word "identité" (or words with the same word stem) as an indicator of a tweet dealing with immigration.
However, the word combination "**carte d'identité**" (ID card) is never actually used in this context. Therefore i would like to **exclude it**.

The original code looks like this:

```
 mutate(identit = str_detect(full_text, "identit"))
```

So far, I tried to exclude it by using the hat operator.

```
  mutate(identit = str_detect(full_text, "[^carte d']identité"))
```

which however actually includes it and articles like l'immigration and d'immigration, whereas words without articles identité or identitaire are excluded.

edit:
In order to make it replicable:

```
 df <- data.frame(text = c("Ma carte d\'identité","Notre identité", "ce n'est pas l'identité du pays", "d'identité", "tasty buns"))
df_detect <- df %>% mutate(identit = str_detect(text, "*???*"))
```

(Basically, in this dataframe I'd like str_detect to only detect ,"Notre identité", "ce n'est pas l'identité du pays", "d'identité")

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which is your desired output and your dataset? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). However something like this without any further informations could work, maybe `df <- data.frame(phrases = c('aDASD carte d\'identité','FSDFSDG identité'));
df[!grepl("carte d\'identité", df$phrases),]`

Comment: This answer may help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Comment: Hi @s__ , thank you! I hope i got you write and added a replicable dataframe. (plus further description)

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with exclusion `[^carte d']` but this treats it as a separate individual letters to exclude preceding your target. You want to use a look around, in particular the "not preceded by" `(?<!)`

```
str_detect(text, "(?<!carte d\')identité")
```

In case you don't have it already, here's a [link to the `stringr` cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/strings.pdf) that has a lot of good information about regular expressions. I know personally reference this no less than 3 times a day if I'm working with text data