# Better way to handle client-side validation with placeholder workaround

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side-validation

I'm doing a javascript workaround for placeholders, such that for broswers that do not recognise it, I display the placeholder using the input/textarea value. But this messes my client side validation on the ASP.net MVC app.

I saw this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882475/handling-placeholders-using-unobtrusive-validation) which is not something I'd like to implement as: (1) I have a few fields that use placeholders, (2) for my placeholder, I use a ModelMetaDataprovider which either returns the DisplayAttribute or the DescriptionAttribute or the name of the field (split into words and properly case-converted).

Now, I also read [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1825758.aspx), which suggests using a custom validation attribute. However, I think this is an overkill since all I wanted is a different client-side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I should have read that [second link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1825758.aspx) better. A guy suggested changing the jquery.validate.js to check for the placeholder attribute of the element. But I took that as a bad solution as that will likely be overwritten with an upgrade of the jquery.validate.js.

However, I discovered I could override the validator method in my our script. So I wrote this which appears to work. Basically, I copied the method but added the lines indicated below.

In my own validation js, I added I replace check to see if the element has a placeholder attribute and if its equals the placeholder text:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    'required',
    function(value, element, param) {
        // check if dependency is met
        if ( !this.depend(param, element) )
            return "dependency-mismatch";
        switch( element.nodeName.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'select':
            // could be an array for select-multiple or a string, both are fine this way
            var val = $(element).val();
            return val && val.length > 0;
        case 'input':
            if ( this.checkable(element) )
                return this.getLength(value, element) > 0;
        default:
            // REPLACED THIS:
            //return $.trim(value).length > 0;
            // WITH THIS:
            return ($.trim(value).length > 0) && (value != element.getAttribute('placeholder'));
        }
    }, '');
```

It appears to work. And running a script debug, I can see it replaces the 'required'.