# Regular expression for checking suffix for both international and national number

Tags: regex, numbers

I need to check numbers, national and international with the same Regex.
I receive numbers on 33ZABPQMCDU and 0ZABPQMCDU formats.

The regex have to accept on 33ZABPQMCDU and 0ZABPQMCDU formats, but refuse numbers on 3389BPQMCDU and 089BPQMCDU formats.

For example

OK :

0545904660

33545904660

KO :

0895904660

33895904660

I don't know how to verify that a number is well constructed, and on the same time to reject  numbers beginning with **089** or **3389**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
(?!^089\d{7}$)
```

excludes 10-digit numbers starting with "089."  Here:

```
/(?!^089\d{7}$)(?!^3389\d{7}$)^(\d{10}\d?)$/
```

Also see [RegEx to exclude a specific string constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant)