# Python Regex to parse email URLs but excluding the public email

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing a file that have entries like:

```
xxx-yy.biz.  39405   A   156.154.66.33
mail.global.com.   3464    A   115.113.9.64
xyx xyx xyx
webmail.xyz.com.  1463    A   115.113.9.64
gmail.com.   3464    A   115.113.9.22
```

I am trying to extact the URL and its IP address with string "mail" in it:

```
for line in (dnsfile):
            match = re.search(r'(.*mail.*?)\s+(.*)\s+A\s+(.*)', line)
```

and match.group(1) and match.group(2) is giving me URL and IP.

I want to extent this search so that I don't want to parse public emails like: gmail, hotmail, yahoo,mail. More general : exclude a list of words in this 
search.

Comment: Plain regexes can't do this, but a "negative lookahead assertion" might help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead, but you need to add the start and end anchors so you need `re.DOTALL` flags too (make the anchors to match from start and end of each line), you can create your negative look-ahead with joining the list of words with `|` :

```
re.search(r'^(?!{})(.*mail.*?)\s+(.*)\s+A\s+(.*)$'.format('|'.join(list_of_domin)),line,re.DOTALL)
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/bF5xQ3/1

Comment: @HasanRamezani Thanks, I think that look-around is a knight in regex world! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a requirement to have it as part of the regexp you could do a simple array search

```
nothanks = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com']
for line in (dnsfile):
    match = re.search(r'(.*mail.*?)\.\s+(.*)\s+A\s+(.*)', line)
    if match:
        if not match.group(1) in nothanks:
            print match.group(1)
```