# String that doesn't contain character group

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote regex for finding urls in text:

```
/(http[^\s]+)/g
```

But now I need same as that but that expression doesn't contain certain substring, for instance I want all those urls which doesn't contain word `google`.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant

Comment: Have you tried ? `(?!^google)`

Comment: @Onilol, that would break the regex because any url that contains `g`, `o`, `l`, or `e` after the protocol would match your condition.  Square brackets means it'll match one character of the group (or not match, with `^`), not the entire string.

Comment: @ps2goat my bad ! Still caffeinating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve that:

```
http:\/\/(?!\S*google)\S+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD2hJ2/2)

JS:

```js
var re = /http:\/\/(?!\S*google)\S+/g; 
var str = 'http://ya.ru http://yahoo.com http://google.com';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += m[0] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Regex breakdown:

- `http:\/\/` - a literal sequence of `http://`
- `(?!\S*google)` - a negative look-ahead that performs a forward check from the current position (i.e. right after `http://`), and if it finds `0-or-more-non-spaces-heregoogle` the match will be cancelled.
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace symbols (this is necessary since the lookahead above does not really *consume* the characters it matches).

Note that if you have any punctuation after the URL, you may add `\b` right at the end of the pattern:

```js
var re1 = /http:\/\/(?!\S*google)\S+/g; 
var re2 = /http:\/\/(?!\S*google)\S+\b/g; 
document.write(
  JSON.stringify(
    'http://ya.ru, http://yahoo.com, http://google.com'.match(re1)
  ) + "<br/>"
);

document.write(
  JSON.stringify(
    'http://ya.ru, http://yahoo.com, http://google.com'.match(re2)
  )
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have little time, I will add some more explanation later. Main thing is that a look-ahead will fail a match if the non-whitespaces contain `google`.

Comment: I added explanation and an enhancement suggestion.