# How to exclude some files and directories from the output of md5deep?

Tags: regex, md5, md5sum

I am using the md5deep utility to compute the hashes for files while recursively digging through a directory structure.

It allows to run command like this -

```
md5deep -r -l -j0 app
```

and gives output like this (recursive list of md5 hash of all the underlying files/directories, considering their content) -

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/controllers/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/models/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/components/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/helpers/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/behaviors/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/groups/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/fixtures/empty
```

I am further doing an `md5sum` on the result to produce a hash of the entire codebase -

```
md5deep -r -l -j0 app | md5sum
```

Output -

```
86df91fc29f2891ff0aa7aaa4bd13730  -
```

Now, I am stuck at excluding some paths (files and directories) from being considered while calculating the final md5sum. E.g. if I want to exclude these two paths - `app/tests/groups/empty` and `app/tests/fixtures/empty`.

The [md5deep documentation](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/md5deep.html) provides an option (`-f` option) to provide a list of file names/directories in a file, but those files will be included. However, I am looking for the opposite, i.e. to exclude some predefined set of files/directories from the dynamic set of directories (new directories/files could be added in future) inside a given directory.

Solutions using regular expressions or some tool/utility other than md5deep are also welcome, as long as it serves my purpose. I feel a regex solution with grep would be complicated, in the absence of lookaheads. E.g. the following regex is needed just to match any string excluding `ABC` -

```
^([^A]|A([^B]|B([^C]|$)|$)|$).*$
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395247/351903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using `find` together with `md5sum`:

```
find app -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/groups/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/components/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/behaviors/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/models/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/helpers/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/controllers/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/fixtures/empty
```

If you need to exclude some directory, use the option `-path` and if you need to exclude filename use `-name`.

For example if you want to exclude file which would contain `models` in their pathname, use the following:

```
find app -type f ! -path "*models*" -exec md5sum {} \;
```

BTW, if your looking at empty files, you can use the `-empty` option: 
`find app -empty`

Comment: Looks good. I have just one question. Is there any possibility of individual md5sums being returned in different order? Because this could lead to different results when I pipe the above output to get a final hash like this - `find app -type f ! -path "*models*" -exec md5sum {} \;`. FYI, the `-j0` in command `md5deep -r -l -j0 app | md5sum` stands for using 1 thread to prevent non-determinism due to individual md5sums being returned in different orders.

Comment: It seems, the above concern will arise if `find` uses multi threading.

Comment: @SandeepanNath The `find` will execute the `md5sum` command sequentially while traversing the whole directory tree. There is no multithreading involved in the command I posted

Comment: Just for the records, correcting myself, in my first comment, I meant `find app -type f ! -path "*models*" -exec md5sum {} \; | md5sum` to get the final hash.

Comment: I also need to be able to ignore multiple paths at a time, e.g. app/config and app/logs. Could you help with the same?

Comment: @SandeepanNath Just add as many `! -path "app/<dir>*"` you want to the command.