# RegEx to select everything After search string, excluding search string

Tags: regex

This differs from other posts in that I need it to MATCH on everything after a search string, excluding the search string.

For example, with "Bob at Ohio State", I need to extract everything after " at ", e.g. in this case "Ohio State".

For the tool I am using, Chrome Web Scraper Extension, I only have the ability to return MATCHED expressions. So I need a matching expression that matches on " at ", and then only returns everything after that.

Comment: I think you mean this post on SO  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant

Comment: [`(?<=\sat\s+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/kUIseM/2)

Comment: Yes Wiktor! Thank you. What if I wanted all the text BEFORE " at "?

Comment: @user2184214: Read [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [here](https://www.rexegg.com) for two good overviews

Comment: Thanks Dawg. But really? If I had the time to read all about RegEx and become an expert, I would be answering questions here on RegEx, and not asking them. That response is not very helpful on a site that is all about helping those who might use a technology sparingly just to get a job done in another technology that is their strength. Just saying. No offense intended.