# Java regex match anything except a single expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace everything except a specific expression including digits in java using only the `replaceAll()` method and a single regex.

Given the String `P=32 N=5 M=2` I want to extract each variable independently. 
I can match the expression `N=5` with the regex `N=\d`, but I can't seem to find an inverse expression that will match anything but `N=\d`, where x may be any digit.

I do not want to use `Pattern` or `Matcher` but solve this using regex only. So for x, y, z being any digit, I want to be able to replace everything but the expression N=y in a String `P=x N=y M=z`:

```
String input = "P=32 N=5 M=2";
output = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(output);
// expected "N=5"
```

Comment: `[A-MO-Z]=\d+` would do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to exclude a specific string constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant)

Comment: You use `\b(?!N=5\b)\w+=\d+`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have tried this, this will match `P=3M=2`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @YCF_L after using `replaceAll(regex, "")` only my String expression, e.g. `N=5`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this will work for the specific case that the String is N=5; I want to match any String N=x where X is any digit

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? `N=\d+`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to match not only N=5 but also possibly e.g. N=1 or N= 12

Comment: [`\b(?!N=\d+\b)\w+=\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/BlMIMr/1)

Comment: Yeah, replace the `5\b` with `\d+\b` or just keep `N=` in the lookahead. It depends on whether your input is messy or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s*\\b(?!N=\\d)\\w+=\\d+", "").trim();
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/fG8z3a) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1dnYS/1).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!N=\d)` - immediately to the right, there should be no `N=` and any digit
- `\w+`  - 1+ letters/digits/`_`
- `=` - an `=` sign
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.