# RegEx to exclude particular words

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am working on RegEx that will match a string that contains only uppercase letters and digits but not exact words ABC or XYZ or LMN.

```
^(?!ABC|XYZ|LMN)([A-Z0-9]+)$
```

This works for most of the cases but fails for input ABC12, XYZ8 etc.

How can I improve this to match the requirement.

I've referred [RegEx to exclude a specific string constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant) but couldn't tackle this one.

Comment: The input for this regEx would be a word with finite length and no sentence that will contain white spaces

Comment: Can you try: `/^(?!(?:ABC|XYZ|LMN)$)[A-Z\d]+$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to match the whole string or line using ^ and $, then you can put the $ inside your negative lookahead. This will allow ABC12 to match.

`^(?!(ABC|XYZ|LMN)$)([A-Z0-9]+)$`