# How do I exclude a matched digit using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the string: `the_number_10_is_important`, I want to capture `_10_` and exclude `10`.

I essentially want to replace all underscores surrounding digits with brackets.

`_\d+_` selects `_10_` is my starting point. I'm trying to use [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or a non-capturing group eg. `_(?:\d+)_`

Comment: See if this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant

Comment: You starting well, but I guess you want \d+ instead of \d to match multiple digits

Comment: Why not simply: `.replace(/_(\d+)_/g, "($1)")` ?

Comment: You have to use a capture group and repeat the digits `"the_number_10_is_important".replace(/_(\d+)_/g, "[$1]");`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Replacing the brackets within `replace` seems to work fine in this case.

Comment: `(?:\d+)` is not a lookaround, that's a non-capturing group, completely unrelated to one another.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this then, with credit to [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)

> You have to use a capture group and repeat the digits `"the_number_10_is_important".replace(/_(\d+)_/g, "[$1]");`

Here's my own version, but with sed which doesn't have proper support for `\d`:

```
sh$ echo "the_number_10_is_important_ but 10 should not be fooled by the real_0_ or the fake_1" | sed -E -e 's/_([0-9]+)_/[\1]/g'
the_number[10]is_important_ but 10 should not be fooled by the real[0] or the fake_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the number and give it back in the replacement, so you replace the whole `_10_` part instead of just the underscores.

```
var s = "the_number_10_is_important";
var x = s.replace(/_(\d+)_/gm, "($1)");
console.log(x);
```

It is possible to do it your way too with lookaround, but it is somewhat more complicated.

```
var s = "the_number_10_is_important";
var x = s.replace(/_(?=\d+)/gm, "(").replace(/(?<=\d+)_/gm, ")");
console.log(x);
```